# about database table design

Tags: sql-server, database

I've done research on the web for a while but couldn't find a same situation. What I need is follow:

I have 20 groups, and each group has its own document template. For example, in group one, the template has 26 contents: A,B,C,D,E.....Z. But not all of these 26 contents will display.

> For example, document 1 will display 10 contents, and document will display 15 contents. In group two, the template has 30 contents: aa1,bb2,cc3,.....yy30. Each document will display certain contents depending on parameters passed, same as group one.

I will create a method with parameters and the documents will be generated based on the parameters passed.

How should I design the database tables in sql server?
1) Use A,B,C,D....Z as columns, the values will be either true(show) or false(not show)?  But each group has different templates. For example, group two will have columns aa, bb, cc.....So I have to create 20 tables for 20 groups? This is not a good strategy? The records be will like:

```
             A      B      C
doc1       true   true   false
doc2       true   true   false
```

2) Use A,B,C,D...Z as rows, the values will be either true(show) or false(not show)? Then they will be many redundant records. For example, document 1 of group 1 will have:

```
doc1   A    true
doc1   B    true
doc1   C    false
...
doc2
doc2
...
doc
```

Please help give advice. Thanks!

Comment: What level of normalization do you want?

Comment: it doesn't matter. We don't care about the normalization level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand about your situation is as under:

- You have 20 groups
- Each group has set of contents
- Each group has multiple document templates
- Each document template has multiple contents as per need.

Considering that you don't care about normalization; you need to create single table as under:

Template Table (Group, Document, Content) and add rows only for those contents that are displayed (i.e. true in your example) for a document of a group.

```
Group   Document    Content
-----   --------    -------
G1      Doc1        A
G1      Doc1        B
G1      Doc2        A
G1      Doc2        B
...
G2      Doc1        AA
G2      Doc1        BB
G2      Doc2        BB
G2      Doc2        EE
...
```

Comment: The drawback for this approach is that if there is a new group, then we will have to insert many rows of records to the table. right?

Comment: We don't need a primary key in this case?

Comment: @user3656901, To implement a change, I consider adding, editing and removing rows a more flexible way compared to creating, modifying or deleting tables or columns. In general, I prefer a database design where DML can help implement changes until and unless DDL is must.